# Developing Flutter iOS plugin packages - Pods folder in Xcode project is empty

Tags: xcode, plugins, package, cocoapods, flutter

I am developing a plugin package for Flutter. I follow the instructions exactly as written in a tutorial here: [Step-2c-add-ios-platform-code-hmswift](https://flutter.io/developing-packages/#step-2c-add-ios-platform-code-hmswift).
It says to open `hello/example/ios/Runner.xcworkspace` with xcode, and then:

> iOS platform code of your plugin is located in Pods/DevelopmentPods/hello/Classes/ in the Project Navigator

But, when I open xcode project as specified, there is nothing under `Pods` folder, it is empty:

[image]

How can I fix this { I am still kinda Xcode noob } ...

EDIT: iOS specific plugin files are there on the disk, so I guess this is just some project file "wiring" bug or something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that with Xcode, I have opened **`Runner.xcodeproj`** instead of **`Runner.xcworkspace`**. Hope this helps other people who did not pay full attention to Flutter Guide, like I did.

Comment: Also make sure to run `flutter build ios --no-codesign` from plugin's `example` directory before opening `Runner.xcworkspace` as specified in [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages#step-2c-add-ios-platform-code-hmswift)